# Nano does not understand qoutation in the url

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I am using nano library to query couch. I am trying to get just the _design documents so I have the following url:

```
nano.get(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(`_all_docs?startkey="_design/"&endkey="_design0"&include_docs=true`)));
```

when I try the above in post man (without encodeURIComponent and stringify) it works but the qutation seems to be an issue with nano.
Any idea how I can get the above url return the list of _design docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. nano.get() should be use to get a specific document by it's id. It should not be used to make custom calls. If you want to call the _all_docs endpoint, you  must use the `db.list()` function.
2. You shouldn't convert the string to a JSON string. It will escapes the double quotes which breaks the URL.
3. To make  your own custom call with nano, you should instead use `nano.request`

In your case, you should do something like this:

```
const db = nano.use(databaseName);
db.list({include_docs:true, startkey:"_design/", endkey:"_design0"});
```